# Are Rhomobile and Appcelerator direct competitors?

Tags: ruby, mobile, appcelerator, rhomobile

Trying to get a feel for Rhomobile vis a vis Appcelerator - thoughts on whether or not they are direct competitors?

Many thanks,
Wes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are direct competitors.

I found this [post](http://www.amlcode.com/2010/07/16/comparison-appinventor-rhomobile-phonegap-appcelerator-webview-and-aml) that compares the following frameworks: App Inventor, DroidDraw, Rhomobile, PhoneGap, Appcelerator, WebView, and AML.

> **Rhodes** is a complete Model-View-Controller framework written in Ruby.
> Rhodes takes your Ruby code and compiles it into native code for
> whatever device(s) you wish to target. This removes the need for you
> to write any code whatsoever in the target devices’ native languages.
>
> **Appcelerator’s Titanium** platform is a very powerful and
> feature-complete solution. It is similar in some ways to Rhodes and
> PhoneGap, but the implementation is a bit different. Titanium
> primarily uses Javascript and JSON code to as the application
> language, though it can make use of Ruby, Python, and PHP scripts.
> Like the other two, it aims to be a complete self-contained library
> that removes the need to write any native platform code (although they
> provide a way to do so if you want to extend the functionality).

Answer (score 5):

Yes Rhomobile and Appcelerator are competitiors i.e they both are used for developing cross platform mobile applications. There is an excellent article comparing the above two along with MoSync and PhoneGap [here](http://floatlearning.com/2011/07/which-cross-platform-framework-is-right-for-me/)